# Why is my cs50 speller code leaking memory?

Tags: c, cs50

This is my unload function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   //line 116 
    while (table[i] != NULL)
    {
        node *tmp = table[i]->next;
        free(table[i]);
        table[i] = tmp;
    }
    return true;
}
```

check50 says my code is leaking memory.

This is where I'm malloc

```
while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Help50 Valgrind says:
==166== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? Take a closer look at line 116 of dictionary.c.

Comment: Does it say where? Any additional info?

Comment: How did you allocate memory for this table?

Comment: Usually written `while table[i] != NULL) { node *tmp = table[i]; table[i] = table[i]->next; free (tmp); }`

Comment: If check50 says it is leaking memory, be sure to run valgrind yourself to get more detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data structure is as follows:

```
const size_t N = /* some value */;

typedef struct _node {
    struct _node *next;
    int data;
} node;

node *table[N];
```

then this loop reliably frees its memory. I now psychic debug by projecting you have the following:

```
typedef struct _node {
    struct _node *next;
    char *data;
} node;
```

where `data` is allocated by `strdup()` or another `malloc()`. In which case you would need to edit your loop body as follows:

```
            node *tmp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]->data);
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = tmp;
```

General rule: pointers in structures are not freed when you free the structure and you have to do it yourself.

Another possibility:

```
size_t N;
node **table;
```

In which case you need at the end of unload

```
    free(table);
    table = NULL;
    N = 0;
```

If neither of these are true, your leak is elsewhere, not to be found in this function.